# Is there a way to write data to csv from 2 dimensional array, without using loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2 dimensional array 'allData(100,2)
Is it possible to write the values from this 2-dimensional array to a csv, without using loop?

currently, I have a code but it uses Interop.
Unfortunately, I need to just use csv because our servers does not support Interop.
Here is my code when using Interop:

xlWorkSheet.Range(rangeCell).Resize(checkedOutItems.Count, 2).Value = allData

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? At some point _something_ will need to iterate over the data.

Comment: As much as possible, I would like to optimize my code because at least a thousand values need to be written in the csv.

Comment: If you want to optimize your code, dropping Excel should be the first step, unless you really, really need it. :) Plus, saving a 2D integer array to a CSV file in a loop takes almost no time, even if you have a 1000 items.

Comment: That's the specification. To produce an excel output :)

Comment: Excel can easily read the .csv file you produce but I guarantee you that your for loop will be faster than Excel. Why do you think using Excel would benefit you in any way?

Comment: Please read my post again....

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to use a loop to write values. Why is that a problem? The Excel interop thing did that, too, except it was way more expensive - you loaded a several megabyte executable to save a few hundred items to disk. If you do it yourself, it'll be much, much faster. The code will be something like (in C#, should be trivial to port to VB.NET but my VB is rusty :)  ):

```
int i;
StringBuilder sbBuffer = new StringBuilder ();

for ( i = 0; i < arr2D.Length; i++ )
{
    sbBuffer.Append ( arr2D[i,0] ).Append ( ',' ).Append ( arr2D[i,1] );
    sbBuffer.AppendLine ();
}

File.WriteAllText ( @"C:\data.csv", sbBuffer.ToString () );
```

If you have a lot of items, you can also use a StreamWriter instead of a StringBuilder - the StringBuilder will keep the entire output in memory until it's done. If you have a lot of data, the StreamWriter will keep writing it to the disk on the fly so you don't use as much memory.

Did I miss something in your post?

Comment: Ok. I added some details about using a StreamWriter if your data is large.